# Selenium ChromeWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running the below test code, and I am getting the error:
**
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
C:\geckodriver.exe: error: Found argument '--websocket-port' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

USAGE:
geckodriver.exe --port

For more information try --help

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:565)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:110)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:94)
at newpackage.Login.main(Login.java:17)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.4.0', revision: 'e5c75ed026a'
, os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_281'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:226)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:547)
... 6 more
**

```
package neoproject;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//comment the above line and uncomment below line to use Chrome
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class PG1 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        //WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
        String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
        String actualTitle = "";

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

        // get the actual value of the title
        actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

        /*
         * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
         * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
         */
        if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test Passed!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
        }
       
        //close Fire fox
        driver.close();
       
    }

}

public class MyClass {

}
```

Thank you in advance for your aasistant.

Answer (score 1):

check your selenium java version and also browser version

once remove your selenium-java dependency and Add  new selenium-java dependency in your pom.xml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).